# Conditional Parent in Bicep

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

I have a Bicep script deployed as part of an Azure Pipeline. Through some googling, I've managed to almost implement a "create if not exists" for resources using a Powershell Script further up the pipeline as described at https://ochzhen.com/blog/check-if-resource-exists-azure-bicep

The issue seems to be I can't pass an ID or a conditional reference as a parent. What I;m trying to do is:

```html
param isFdEndpointExisting bool
...
resource endpoint 'Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/afdEndpoints@2020-09-01' =if(!isFdEndpointExisting) {
  name: fdEndpointName
  parent: fdProfile
  ... //  params to initialize here
}

resource endpointExisting 'Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/afdEndpoints@2020-09-01'existing =if(isFdEndpointExisting) {
  name: fdEndpointName
  parent: fdProfile
}

resource route 'Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/afdEndpoints/routes@2020-09-01' =if(!isFdRouteExisting) {
  name: routeName
  parent: isFdEndpointExisting ? endpointExisting : endpoint
```

The error I get is:
`The "parent" property only permits direct references to resources. Expressions are not supported.bicep(BCP240)`

Is there an alternative way of doing this. It feels a little clunky.

Comment: you could create the route in its own module after getting or creating the endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create the endpoint inside a module:

```
// fd-route.bicep

param frontDoorName string
param endpointName string
param routeName string

... 
resource frontDoor 'Microsoft.Cdn/profiles@2022-11-01-preview'existing = {
  name: frontDoorName
}

resource endpoint 'Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/afdEndpoints@2022-11-01-preview'existing = {
  parent: frontDoor
  name: endpointName  
}

resource route 'Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/afdEndpoints/routes@2020-09-01' = {
  parent: endpoint
  name: routeName
  ...
}
```

Then you can invoke it like that from your main

```
param isFdEndpointExisting bool
param fdProfileName string
param fdEndpointName string
param routeName string 

...

// Get a ference to front door
resource fdProfile 'Microsoft.Cdn/profiles@2020-09-01' existing = {
  name: fdProfileName
}

// Create the endpoit if not exists
resource endpoint 'Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/afdEndpoints@2020-09-01' =if(!isFdEndpointExisting) {
  parent: fdProfile
  name: fdEndpointName  
  ...  
}

// Get a reference to the existing endpoint if already exists
resource endpointExisting 'Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/afdEndpoints@2020-09-01'existing =if(isFdEndpointExisting) {
  name: fdEndpointName
  parent: fdProfile
}

// Create the rouyte
module route 'fd-route.bicep' = {
  name: routeName
  params: {
    frontDoorName: fdProfile.name
    endpointName: isFdEndpointExisting ? endpointExisting.name : endpoint.name
    routeName: routeName
    ...
  }
}
```